# pinterest web scrape image

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, cheerio

I'm trying to get a url from a pinterest image and send a url of it through the general profile of the user on pinterest, but it's returning me undefined

[image]

my code:

```
const Command = require("../../structures/Command");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const rp = require("request-promise");
const { head } = require("request");

module.exports = class Pinterest extends Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client);
    this.client = client;

    this.name = "pinterest";
    this.category = "Dono";
    this.aliases = [];

    this.enabled = true;
    this.guildOnly = true;
  }
  async run({ message, args, prefix, author }, t) {
    if (
      message.author.id !== "196679829800747017"
    )
      return;

      const URL = (`https://br.pinterest.com/n1cotin3/_created/`)
      const headerObj = {
          uri: URL
      };
      rp(headerObj)
      .then(html => {
          var $ = cheerio.load(html)

          const avatar = $("#mweb-unauth-container > div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > div.F6l.ZZS.k1A.zI7.iyn.Hsu > div > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div > div > div > a > div > div > div > div > div.XiG.zI7.iyn.Hsu > img").attr("src")
          console.log(avatar)
    message.react(``);
  })
}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the page is still loading. `#mweb-unauth-container > div > div:nth-child(2)` doesn't exist, because `#mweb-unauth-container > div` only has one div child, and it's a loading icon. I don't think this is something you can do with cheerio, you'll have to use an alternative that can resolve Javascript (such as Puppeteer).

Alternatively, if you don't want to scrape, you can use a private API (which, although subject to change at any point, would *definitely* be more performant):

`https://widgets.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/users/n1cotin3/pins/`

Example:

```js
const res = await requestThatEnpointSomehow();
const images = res.data.pins.map(({ images }) => images['564x']);

// `images` will be a list of URLs.
```

Comment: const images = res.data.pins.map(({ images }) => images["564x"]);
                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at C:\Área de Trabalho\Squiford\src\commands\Owner\pinterest.js:26:38
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Comment: `res` might be different depending on how you're fetching the data, but it should be easy to fix. Just `console.log(res)` and figure out the structure from there :)

Comment: data: {
    status: 'success',
    code: 0,
    data: { user: [Object], pins: [Array] },
    message: 'ok',
    endpoint_name: 'v3_pidget_get_user_pins'
  }

Comment: Ok, then it should be `res.data.data.pins.map(({ images }) => images["564x"])`